# What should be put in a "module" or "group" in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193816/use-of-sections-within-a-module-group-in-doxygen) but a little more specific.  What are the intended elements put inside a group or module?  If I put the entire file including the @file construct, the file is still listed in the global files section.  If I do not, it makes a little more sense but there is still no synopsis and the detail text describing the module is gone.  Even when the detail text is there, it is not at the top and hard to find.  A reference to it doesn't go the the detail section but instead goes to the module.  I've come to believe that it must be intended for some other purpose.  My question is what is the purpose or it?  What things are intended to be put into a group?

Answer (score 0):

The often-missed value of Doxygen Groups is that they enable you to bring together (in your document) things that are logically related *but are separated in the code*.

Consider you have two modules / classes / whatever.  One is **Bowl** and one is **Fruit**.  Each is a separate code **Module** and should be kept so, and is so described in the doxygen output.

However, you want to give the user some guidance on how to create bowls of fruit.

By using `ingroup Fruitbowls` in the relevant sections of the code in Bowl and in Fruit, the resulting documentation automatically describes what you need for Fruit, Bowls, *and* Fruitbowls with no additional text (except that the `\defgroup fruitbowls` allows you somewhere to introduce the assembling of fruitbowls from the classes Fruit and Bowl, and so on).

Essentially a Group is a way of gathering together code sections that share a logical use, rather than a code structure (i.e. Module).

Comment: You missed the gist of my question.  "By using ingroup Fruitbowls in the relevant sections of the code" -- what are the relevant sections?  Is it "file" or just particular structures or just functions or all three?  @sections do not work well.  All of the others have problems.

Comment: The `@section` command is for organising plain text - it has nothing whatsoever to do with code.  By 'relevant sections' I mean whatever you choose is relevant to (in my example) Fruitbowls, by surrounding it with `@ingroup @{` and `@}`.  It is entirely your choice whether you surround particular structures, methods, or the whole file.

Comment: A simpler approach to using Groups (if you don't want this matrix benefit) is simply to wrap the contents of multiple related files with the same group name.  This is probably more relevant to C than OO languages tho'.

Comment: You are still completely missing the question.

Comment: Fair enough; I think you're still completely missing the point of groups.  I've tried to answer "What things are intended to be put into a group?".  If that's not the question I suggest you rephrase it.

Comment: You have answered what groups are for... not what to put into them.  e.g. do I put @file into them?  Do I put structures into them?  Do I put functions into them?  In each case, I don't get output that seems to make sense.  The question I pointed to speaks of some of the issues.  I thought, maybe, there were something besides files, structures, or functions.  But I guess not.